# Blaze Media Pro 10 - Video Edit does nothing

Tags: windows-7, video, video-editing

I have downloaded a software called Blaze Media Pro 10 from its official site. It’s a 15 day trial software. It's an Audio Video Editor.
I have installed it on my Windows 7 SP1 64 bit. The installation went fine and smooth.

Now when I run the software, it does open up the main window, however each option (Edit Audio, Edit Video, DVD Rip) etc. is supposed to open a new window on top for editing.

When I click ‘Edit Audio’ the audio editor window opens successfully.

However when I click on ‘Edit Video’ absolutely nothing happens. The app does not do anything.
When I click on ‘Video Merge’ it throws a runtime error 339 (Videoedit.ocx not correctly registered) and abruptly exits.

I have written to official support  but probably since I am not yet a registered paid user, they have not responded yet.

I even tried running the program in compatibility mode with Windows XP SP3 as well as ‘As Admin’ but same results.

There's no mention on official website that Video Edit functionality is not present in trial ware. The description therein shows all features.

Does anyone have any idea what’s going wrong. Did I miss something?

My desktop PC fulfills all minimum system requirements for this program as stated [here](http://www.blazemp.com/blaze_media_pro.asp) for software v10.

[image]

Comment: "What are the recommended operating system configurations for Blaze Media Pro? Windows 98 Second Edition, Windows ME, Windows 2000, Windows XP, Windows 2003, or Windows Vista (All Versions)." Windows 7 or later are not in the list of supported versions.

Comment: @ DavidPostill Thanks for the comment. However please check here http://www.blazemp.com/blaze_media_pro.asp For V10 it clearly states that Windows 7/8/10 both 32 & 64 bit are supported. Up to Vista might have been the case with earlier versions of this program but not for V10. All system requirements were checked before download. My system fulfills all other stated requirements too.  I will edit the question to include these details.